# What do you call the little pads under the mouse?

Tags: mouse

The ones that are attached to the mouse, usually they are glued on and make the mouse move around smoother because they are like little smooth feet. My mouse has lost them and I want to buy new ones but I don't know what to look for.

Comment: sometimes they are called feet.....https://www.amazon.com/Fliders-FBA_UNIVERSAL-Replacement-Mouse-Feet/dp/B0049ZAPPW

Comment: I eventually found them for sale as "mouse skates" as well, whats even better is that they go for €1 for a 10x7cm sticky teflon piece that you can cut yourself in chinese estores